# Algebra / Equation with 2 or more vaiables

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebra-precalculus

A train moves past a telegraph post and a bridge 264 m long in 8 seconds and 20 seconds 
respectively. What is the speed of the train?

[image]

I'm really confused if there are 2 or more variables. Can someone explain this in step by step? How x is removed until the end. Thanks.

Or a link on any tutorial or article regarding this. I don't know what to search, I only find simple examples with 1 variable. Thanks.

Comment: Is $x=8y$!!! (Why???)

Comment: I really don't know. That is why I'm asking here. I'm just studying some example.

Comment: I think you need to give some more information or explanation so that anybody can answer your question.

Comment: I've edited it. I put the question in the first line.

Comment: Thank you for your edit and next time explain your problem as much as you can so that you get better solution of your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let the length of the train is $x\,\, m$ and speed of the train is $y \,\,m/s$
So you have $x=8y$ and $x+264=20y$.Hence your result is true.

If you have two variable then you must have two equation and from that you can solve the problem.

Comment: Ah, it's just substituted. I did not comprehend it well. Thanks.

Comment: @StalkerkaNOOB: you welcome.